# What are the possible command line arguments of WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(string [] args)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I often use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` to start my kestrel server on my ASP.NET Core application, with `args` taken from the command line. 
I cannot find anywhere the documentation of what could be those command line arguments. 
My goal is to change the listen port while launching my application without editing any configuration file.

```
public class Program
{
    // I need to change listening port by specifying args
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

ASP.NET Core 2.1/.NET Core 2.2

Comment: Did you see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration)? It suggests you can use e.g. `--urls http://localhost:1234`.

Answer (score 1):

The `args` are passed to the configuration via the [command line configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.commandlineconfigurationextensions.addcommandline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-commandlineconfigurationextensions-addcommandline(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfigurationbuilder-system-string())) extension.

That way you can set every configuration variable available. To set the startup url you can use the `applicationUrl` setting.

I.e. `--applicationUrl='https://localhost:2222'`